# Operation with Complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

We've the following 3 complex numbers

$z_1=2\text{cis}(\frac{\pi}{6})~~$,  $z_2=2\text{cis}(\frac{5\pi}{6})~~$, $z_3=2\text{cis}(\frac{-\pi}{2})$

We are asked to show that $z_1^{3n}+z_2^{3n}=2z_3^{3n}$

I have calculated $z_1^{3n}=2^{3n}\text{cis}(\frac{n\pi}{2})~~$, $z_2^{3n}=2^{3n}\text{cis}(\frac{5n\pi}{2})~~$, 
$z_3^{3n}=2^{3n}\text{cis}(\frac{-3n\pi}{2})$.

I'm stuck on how to proceed further to prove the above equations.  Any help really appreciated, Please assist .

Thank you ,
Arif

Comment: What is "cis" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cis_(mathematics)).

Comment: @dxiv Thanks. I understand now the pedagogical interest of this notation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- $z_1^3 = 2^3 \operatorname{cis}\left(3 \cdot \cfrac{\pi}{6}\right)=8\operatorname{cis}\left(\cfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=8i$
- $z_2^3 = 2^3 \operatorname{cis}\left(3 \cdot \cfrac{5 \pi}{6}\right)=8\operatorname{cis}\left(\cfrac{5 \pi}{2}\right)=8\operatorname{cis}\left(2\pi+\cfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=8\operatorname{cis}\left(\cfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=8i$
- $z_3^3 = 2^3 \operatorname{cis}\left(-3 \cdot \cfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=8\operatorname{cis}\left(- 3 \cdot \cfrac{\pi}{2}+ 2 \pi\right)=8\operatorname{cis}\left(\cfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=8i$

Therefore $\;z_1^3=z_2^3=z_3^3\,$.